# Combining letter spacing and different font weights in section heading

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, fontspec, letterspacing

I want a to define a section heading that features:

- a light and a bold font weight
- adjusted letter spacing
- a local truetype font (fontspec package)
- correct referencing in pdf table of contents

This is what came closest:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\hypersetup{%
  plainpages=false,
  colorlinks=false,
  pdfborder={0 0 0},
  breaklinks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  bookmarksopen=true
}%

\usepackage{kantlipsum}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont[%
  Path           = /usr/share/fonts/truetype/OpenSans/,
  Extension      = .ttf,
  Ligatures      = TeX,
  BoldFont       = OpenSans-Semibold,
  ItalicFont     = OpenSans-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = OpenSans-BoldItalic
]{OpenSans-Light}%

\newfontfamily{\OSLight}{Open Sans Light}%
\newfontfamily{\OSBold}{Open Sans Bold}%

\newcommand\ibsection[2]{{\section{\OSLight{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-5}#1} \OSBold{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-5}#2}}}}%


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\ibsection{Der Philosoph}{Immanuel Kant}

\kant[1]

\ibsection{Der}{kategorische Imperativ}

\kant[2]

{\Large \OSLight{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-5} Der Philosoph }\OSBold{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=-5} Immanuel Kant}}

\end{document}
```

This solution is not satisfying for two reasons:

1. The *light* font weight of the section heading is rather *regular* than *light*. Please see image. I want the heading to be like it is at the bottom.
2. The table of contents within the pdf file shows the text *LetterSpace=-5*. Please also see the image below.

[image: mwe]

I know there is `microtype` package with a letter spacing option. Not applicable here as I use fontspec package and XeLaTeX.

I am also aware of `opensans` package. Not an option because I want to be able to use other locally stored fonts.

The question of course is, how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You can move the Letterspace-option to the font definition: `\newfontfamily{\OSLight}{Open Sans Light}[LetterSpace=-5]` and in the section add `\mdseries` `\newcommand\ibsection[2]{\section{{\OSLight \mdseries #1} {\OSBold #2}}}`. Imho your layout looks rather ugly.

Comment: Great. The `\mdseries` does change the font weight. Moving the letterspace option to the font definition as you suggest produces an error: `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`. I assume it worked for you. Any idea why it didn't for me?

Comment: Too old fontspec? Try `\newfontfamily{\OSLight}[LetterSpace=-5]{Open Sans Light}`